# BCD adder and Decimal Output

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, digit, bcd, vlsi

For Calculating `Decimal Output` of  `125 * A - 100 * (A Mod 4) + 2` with having A ( `one BCD digit`) Which of the following is True?

1) we need at least two decimal adder.

2) we need at least two 4-bit binary adder.

3) we need at least one decimal multiplier and one decimal adder.

4) Non of the above.

Why our instructor select `(4)` as a solution and not selected `(3)`? any idea or hint?

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A Mod 4` in the original equation gives the two least significant bits of the BCD digit `A`. So, let's consider the two most and least significant bits of A separately, like so:

```
X = A AND 3 = A Mod 4  (two least significant bits)
Y = A AND Ch           (two most significant bits)
```

where the `h` suffix in `Ch` means `C` in hexadecimal (i.e. `Ch` is `1100` in binary), and `AND` denotes the logical AND operation.

For example, if we had

```
A = abcd
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are arbitrary binary digits, we would get

```
X = 00cd
Y = ab00
```

Importantly, note that

```
A = X + Y
(ab00 + 00cd = abcd)
```

This allows us to apply distributivity of the multiplication over the addition, specifically

```
  125 * A
= 125 * (X + Y)
= 125 * X + 125 * Y
```

So, we have

```
  125 * A - 100 * (A Mod 4) + 2     (original equation)
= 125 * (X + Y) - 100 * X + 2       (replace A with X + Y)
= 125 * Y + 125 * X - 100 * X + 2   (distributivity)
= 125 * Y + 25 * X + 2              (125 * X - 100 * X = 25 * X)
= 100 * Y + 25 * (X + Y)            (125 * Y = 100 * Y + 25 * Y)
= 100 * Y + 25 * A + 2              (replace X + Y with A)
```

In the final equation `100 * Y + 25 * A + 2`, there are two terms we need to compute (`100 * Y` and `25 * A`), plus one constant term (`2`).

The term `100 * Y` is easy in BCD: just shift `Y` two digit positions to the left, to the hundreds digit.

For the `25 * A` term, we need a multipler to multiply `A` by 25.

Now, we need to add all three terms together, but:

- There is no overlap between the set bits (the "one" bits) in terms `100 * Y` and `25 * A`. Indeed, term `100 * Y` can only set the two most significant bits of the hundreds digit (go back to the definition of `Y`), while term `25 * A` will at most set the two least significant bits of that same digit position. To see that, remember that `25 * A = 100 * A / 4`, meaning the hundreds digit cannot be more than 3 for that term.
- Both terms `100 * Y` and `25 * A` are multiples of 25, which means their sum is as well, so the lower digit of that sum can only be 0 (0000) or 5 (0101). The second bit cannot be set in that sum, so there is also no overlap with the constant `2` term.

Since all three terms do not overlap when considering which bit positions can be set, we can add all three with a simple logical OR operation instead of an actual adder.

In fact, in all we've done, at no point was an adder ever necessary, which means 4) is the only appropriate answer.

Comment: would you please add a bit more detail for the first three line? i couldent get it !

Comment: @user4249446 I apologize for taking so long to come back to this answer. The beginning indeed needed improvement, and I have fixed that, hoping it is still useful. Please review, and do not hesitate to ask if anything else is not clear.

Comment: thanks so much, i approve it. would you please describe a bit more on X = A And 3  = A Mod 4 (low part), Y = A And Ch = A - A MOD 4 (high part)? thanks so much.

Comment: @user4249446 Done :) The `A - A MOD 4` part was actually superfluous information since I added the clearer remark about `A` being equal to `X + Y`, so I removed it, which should make things less confusing. I also added emphasis on the `abcd` example to better show what we are trying to accomplish. Is it more understandable like this?